# Solving $\frac{\ln(x)\ln(y)}{\ln(1-x)\ln(1-y)}=1$ for $y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> I'm trying to solve for $y$ in terms of $x$ for the expression below.
>
> $$\frac{\ln(x)\ln(y)}{\ln(1-x)\ln(1-y)}=1$$

First I multiplied both sides by $$ \frac{\ln(1-x)}{\ln(x)} $$

to get

$$ \frac{\ln(y)}{\ln(1-y)}=\frac{\ln(1-x)}{\ln(x)} $$

but I don't see how to isolate $y.$ I tried using every technique I know including logarithm properties.

Comment: @TheMadcapLaughs: you should delete that at once !

Comment: Uhm... thats not how logs work...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The function $f(x)=\dfrac{\ln(1-x)}{\ln(x)}$ is monotonic in its domain $(0,1)$, hence it is invertible. So the relation between $x$ and $y$ is a bijection, and…

$$y=1-x.$$

---

Interestingly, the function is well approximated by $\left(\dfrac1x-1\right)^{-3/2}$, and a solution with $a$ in the RHS is approximately

$$\left(\dfrac1x-1\right)^{-3/2}=a\left(\dfrac1y-1\right)^{3/2},$$ or

$$y=\frac{1-x}{1+(a^{2/3}-1)x}.$$

Comment: +1, very clever

Comment: okay I just came to that conclusion myself, thanks

Comment: just curious what happens when the $1$ on the RHS becomes $2$ or $3$?

Comment: @Aqua: why should I prove that (which is false) ??

Comment: Sorry, I meant this. How do you prove $\lim_{x→1−}f(x)=0$? It has nothing to do with the problem, but I'm interested since I want to draw a graph.

Answer (score 2):

If it helps:
$$\frac{\ln{(y)}}{\ln{(1-y)}} = \frac{\ln{(1-x)}}{\ln{(x)}}$$
$$e^{\frac{\ln{(y)}}{\ln{(1-y)}}} = e^\frac{\ln{(1-x)}}{\ln{(x)}}$$ 
$$ {{e^{\ln{(y)}}}^{\frac{1}{\ln{(1-y)}}}} =  {{e^{\ln{(1-x)}}}^{\frac{1}{\ln{(x)}}}}$$
$$y^{\frac{1}{\ln{(1-y)}}} = (1-x)^{\frac{1}{\ln{(x)}}}$$
$$y^{\ln{(x)}} = (1-x)^{\ln{(1-y)}}$$

---

From here you can make a substitution:
$1-y = t$.

---

And you get:
$$(1-t)^{\ln{x}} = (1-x)^{\ln{(t)}}$$
Since both $\ln{x}$ and $e^x$ are injective it follows:
$$x = t$$
And since $t = 1-y$, we conclude:
$$y = 1-x $$

Answer (score 1):

Because, in the general case, the equation depends on two algebraically independent monomials ($\ln(y),\ln(1-y))$, the equation cannot be solved for $y$ by only *rearranging* it by applying only finite numbers of [elementary functions/operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function).

Other tricks, Special functions, numerical or series solutions could help.