# Finding the area under $\frac{\ln(x)\ln(y)}{\ln(1-x)\ln(1-y)}=n$ from $x=0,1$

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus, definite-integrals, implicit-function

This relates to my recent question:

[Solving $\frac{\ln(x)\ln(y)}{\ln(1-x)\ln(1-y)}=1$ for $y$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3485736/solving-frac-lnx-lny-ln1-x-ln1-y-1-for-y).

Now I'm trying to integrate the following expression but am having trouble putting it in a form in which I can integrate it.

$$\frac{\ln(x)\ln(y)}{\ln(1-x)\ln(1-y)}=n$$

for $n\in\Re(0,\infty)$ and $\ln(1-x)\ln(1-y) \ne0.$ For $n=1$ it's obvious that the area is $1/2.$ However I can't be exact for other values of $n.$

I tried applying the knowledge I learned from the answer to my recent question, but have not had any luck so far.

Comment: What is $\mathfrak R(0,\infty)$? Do you mean the set of positive reals?

Comment: Yep that’s exactly what I mean yifan

Comment: I've never seen that denoted that way before; its usually just $(0,\infty)$, or some variant of $\mathbb R_{>0}$ with `\mathbb{R}` instead of `\mathfrak{R}`.

Comment: Or if you are lazy like me, just `\Bbb R`

Comment: The vast majority of continuous functions you can write out do not have easily expressed anti-derivatives. When you cannot even find a closed expression for $y$ in terms of $x$, you are not likely to find a nice anti-derivative here. If it is even possible to find a simple expression for the integral at all, it will probably require other techniques.